# How can I easily label my data in Power BI?

Tags: mapping, powerbi, data-visualization

## Question

Is there a fast, scalable way to replace number values by mapped text labels in my visualisations?

## Background

I often find myself with questionnaire data of the following format:

```
ID    Sex    Age class    Answer to question
001    1     2            5
002    2     3            2
003    1     3            1
004    2     5            1
```

The `Sex`, `Age class` and `Answer` column values actually map to text labels. For the example of `Sex`:

```
ID    Description
0     Unknown
1     Man
2     Woman
```

Similar mappings are possible for the other columns.

If I create visualisations of e.g. the distribution of sex in my respondent group I'll get a visual showing that 50% of my data has sex `1` and 50% of my data has sex `2`.

The data itself often originates from an Excel or csv file.

## What I have tried

To make that visualisation meaningful to other people I:

- create a second table containing the mapping between the value and label
- create a relationship between the source data and the mapping
- use the `Description` column of my mapping table as a category in my visualisations.

I have to do this for several columns in my dataset, which makes this a tedious process.

## Ideal solution

A method that allows me to define, per column, a mapping between values and corresponding text labels. [SPSS' `VALUE LABELS` command comes to mind](http://www.statsmakemecry.com/smmctheblog/using-syntax-to-assign-variable-labels-and-value-labels-in-s.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a calculated column on your table that defines how you want to map each ID values using a `SWITCH` function and use that column in your visual. For example,

```
Sex Label =
SWITCH([Sex],
    1, "Man",
    2, "Woman",
    "Unknown"
)
```

(Here, the last argument is an *else* condition that gets returned if none of the previous get matched.)

---

If you want to do a whole bunch at a time, you can create a new table from your existing table using `ADDCOLUMNS` like this:

```
Test =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    Table1,
    "Sex Label", SWITCH([Sex], 1, "Man", 2, "Woman", "Unknown"),
    "Question 1 Label", SWITCH([Question 1], 1, "Yes", 2, "No", "Don't Know"),
    "Question 2 Label", SWITCH([Question 2], 1, "Yes", 2, "No", "Don't Know"),
    "Question 3 Label", SWITCH([Question 3], 1, "Yes", 2, "No", "Don't Know")
)
```

Comment: That is an option, but still requires me to go through every column that requires labels. I am looking for something where I can quickly define the mapping for multiple columns in one go.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that. How many columns do you have to label such that it's not practical to do what I suggested?

Comment: Almost 40. It's questionnaire data with for each question a column. A lot of them have "yes" coded as "1", "no" as "2" and "don't know" as "3".